# is it possible to generate subtitles without having any .srt or .vtt file?

Tags: html, video, amazon-s3, subtitle, jwplayer7

I have videos hosted in Amazon S3 and am using JW player 7 javascript version. My videos don't have subtitles but I'd like to add them. I did some research but can't find any tool which will generate subtitles automatically from video file **without** having any .srt or .vtt file. Do you know any online tool which can do this ?

Comment: What, do you expect the browser to transcribe the video for you?

Comment: @duskwuff almost yes, or is there any software which can do this ?

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/mavis/attribution.aspx